# How to use FeatureUnion to combine two lists

Tags: machine-learning

I write this code for FeatureUnion to combine two lists:

```
all_features = FeatureUnion([twenty_train_data, twenty_train_pos])
twenty_train_data "contains words"
twenty_train_pos "contains pos tags"
```

But I got this error:

> all_features = FeatureUnion([twenty_train_data, twenty_train_pos])
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line
>   618, in **init**
>           self._validate_transformers()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line
>   649, in _validate_transformers
>           names, transformers = zip(*self.transformer_list)
>       ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: what exactly is  twenty_train_pos? the transformer_weights?

Comment: No, those are pos tags for the corresponding words in twenty_train_data

Comment: this is the problem . see here [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) you pass 2 arguments but it takes one ! this is explained also by the error: ValueError: too many values to unpack. You only need to pass the  'transformer_list' argument